# Problem using 74HC595 with ULN2803A as LED driver

Tags: arduino-uno, rtc, shift-register

For a final project I'm making a word clock using three 74HC595 registers and three ULN2803A transistor arrays as led drivers, as well as a DS1307 RTC.

The program works great, except for one large problem. While chips 2 and 3 work correctly, the outputs of the first chip are always lit. 
I've tried several different programs online, I've done a lot of research and I just couldn't find the answer.
[image: Schematic]
The code:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Time.h>
#include <DS1307RTC.h>

#define BUTTON_HOUR 8
#define BUTTON_MINUTE 7
#define DATA 2                    // digital 2 to pin 14 on the 74HC595
#define LATCH 3                   // digital 3 to pin 12 on the 74HC595
#define CLOCK 4                   // digital 4 to pin 11 on the 74HC595

// Variables will change:
int buttonStateHOUR = 0;          // current state of the button
int buttonStateMINUTE = 0;        // current state of the button
int lastButtonStateHOUR = 0;      // previous state of the button
int lastButtonStateMINUTE = 0;    // previous state of the button

byte registerByte1 = 0;           // 0 IT IS | 1 FIVE  | 2 EIGHT | 3 QUARTER | 4 THREE  | 5 TEN | 6 MINUTES  | 7 TWENTY
byte registerByte2 = 0;           // 0 TO    | 1 PAST  | 2 HALF | 3 FIVE    | 4 ONE   | 5 NINE | 6 TWO | 7 THREE
byte registerByte3 = 0;           // 0 FOUR   | 1 SIX | 2 EIGHT| 3 SEVEN  | 4 TWELVE | 5 TEN | 6 ELEVEN  | 7 O'CLOCK

tmElements_t tm;

void setup()
{
  // ***********************************
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) ; // wait for serial
  delay(200);
  Serial.println("DS1307RTC Read Test");
  Serial.println("-------------------");
  // ***********************************

  // Buttons
  pinMode(BUTTON_HOUR, INPUT);
  pinMode(BUTTON_MINUTE, INPUT);

  // Shift Register
  pinMode(LATCH, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(CLOCK, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DATA, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  // read the pushbutton input pin:
  buttonStateHOUR = digitalRead(BUTTON_HOUR);
  buttonStateMINUTE  = digitalRead(BUTTON_MINUTE);

  // Detect HOUR Button
  if (buttonStateHOUR != lastButtonStateHOUR) {
    if (buttonStateHOUR == HIGH) {
      addTime(1,0);
    }
    lastButtonStateHOUR = buttonStateHOUR;
  }
  // Detect MINUTE Button
  if (buttonStateMINUTE != lastButtonStateMINUTE) {
    if (buttonStateMINUTE == HIGH) {
      addTime(0,1);
    }
    lastButtonStateMINUTE = buttonStateMINUTE;
  }

  // Generate time and shiftOut
  timeToBytes();
  updateShiftRegisters();
  printTime();
}


void timeToBytes()
{
  if (RTC.read(tm)) {
    int deutschHour = shortHour(tm.Hour);
    int halb = 0;
    registerByte1 = 0;
    registerByte2 = 0;
    registerByte3 = 0;
    bitSet(registerByte1,0);    // "ES IST"

    if (tm.Minute >= 0 && tm.Minute <= 5) {
      bitSet(registerByte1,1);    // "FIVE"
      bitSet(registerByte1,6);    // "MINUTES"
      bitSet(registerByte2,1);    // "PAST"
    } else if (tm.Minute >= 10 && tm.Minute <= 19) {
      bitSet(registerByte1,5);    // "TEN"
      bitSet(registerByte1,6);    // "MINUTES"
      bitSet(registerByte2,1);    // "PAST"
    } else if (tm.Minute >= 20 && tm.Minute <= 24) {
      bitSet(registerByte1,7);    // "TWENTY"
      bitSet(registerByte1,6);    // "MINUTES"
      bitSet(registerByte2,1);    // "PAST"
    } else if (tm.Minute >= 25 && tm.Minute <= 29) {
      bitSet(registerByte1,7);    // "TWENTY"
      bitSet(registerByte1,1);    // "FIVE"
      bitSet(registerByte1,6);    // "MINUTES"
      bitSet(registerByte2,1);    // "PAST"
      halb = 1;
    } else if (tm.Minute >= 30 && tm.Minute <= 34) {
      bitSet(registerByte2,2);    // "HALF"
      bitSet(registerByte2,1);    // "PAST"
      halb = 1;
    } else if (tm.Minute >= 35 && tm.Minute <= 39) {
      bitSet(registerByte1,7);    // "TWENTY"
      bitSet(registerByte1,1);    // "FIVE"
      bitSet(registerByte1,6);    // "MINUTES"
      bitSet(registerByte2,0);    // "TO"
      halb = 1;
    } else if (tm.Minute >= 40 && tm.Minute <= 49)  {
      bitSet(registerByte1,3);    // "QUARTER"
      bitSet(registerByte2,0);    // "TO"
      halb = 1;
    } else if (tm.Minute >= 50 && tm.Minute <= 54) {
      bitSet(registerByte1,5);    // "TEN"
      bitSet(registerByte1,6);    // "MINUTES"
      bitSet(registerByte2,0);    // "TO"
      halb = 1;
    } else if (tm.Minute >= 55 && tm.Minute <= 59) {
      bitSet(registerByte1,1);    // "FIVE"
      bitSet(registerByte1,6);    // "MINUTES"
      bitSet(registerByte2,0);    // "TO"
      halb = 1;
    } 

    deutschHour = shortHour( deutschHour + halb);
    if ( deutschHour == 1 ) {
      bitSet(registerByte2,4);    // "ONE"
    } else if ( deutschHour == 2 ) {
      bitSet(registerByte2,6);    // "TWO"
    } else if ( deutschHour == 3 ) {
      bitSet(registerByte2,7);    // "THREE"
    } else if ( deutschHour == 4 ) {
      bitSet(registerByte3,0);    // "FOUR"
    } else if ( deutschHour == 5 ) {
      bitSet(registerByte2,3);    // "FIVE"
    } else if ( deutschHour == 6 ) {
      bitSet(registerByte3,1);    // "SIX"
    } else if ( deutschHour == 7 ) {
      bitSet(registerByte3,3);    // "SEVEN"
    } else if ( deutschHour == 8 ) {
      bitSet(registerByte3,2);    // "EIGHT"
    } else if ( deutschHour == 9 ) {
      bitSet(registerByte2,5);    // "NINE"
    } else if ( deutschHour == 10 ) {
      bitSet(registerByte3,5);    // "TEN"
    } else if ( deutschHour == 11 ) {
      bitSet(registerByte3,6);    // "ELEVEN"
    } else if ( deutschHour == 12 ) {
      bitSet(registerByte3,4);    // "TWELVE"
    }
    bitSet(registerByte3,7);    // "UHR"
  }
}

void updateShiftRegisters()
{
   digitalWrite(LATCH, LOW);
   shiftOut(DATA, CLOCK, MSBFIRST, registerByte3);
   shiftOut(DATA, CLOCK, MSBFIRST, registerByte2);
   shiftOut(DATA, CLOCK, MSBFIRST, registerByte1);
   digitalWrite(LATCH, HIGH);
}

void addTime(int addHour, int addMinute)
{
  // get time from RTC
  if (RTC.read(tm)) {

    if (addHour > 0) {
      tm.Hour = tm.Hour + addHour;
      if (tm.Hour > 12) {
        tm.Hour = tm.Hour - 12;
      }
    }

    if (addMinute > 0) {
      tm.Minute = tm.Minute + addMinute;
      if (tm.Minute > 59) {
        tm.Minute = tm.Minute - 60;
        addTime(1,0);
      }
    }  

    tm.Second = 0;
    RTC.write(tm); 
  }
}

int shortHour(int tempHour)
{
  tempHour = tempHour % 12;
  return tempHour == 0 ? 12 : tempHour;
}









void printTime() {

  if (RTC.read(tm)) {
    Serial.print("Ok, Time = ");
    print2digits(tm.Hour);
    Serial.write(':');
    print2digits(tm.Minute);
    Serial.write(':');
    print2digits(tm.Second);
    Serial.print(", Date (D/M/Y) = ");
    Serial.print(tm.Day);
    Serial.write('/');
    Serial.print(tm.Month);
    Serial.write('/');
    Serial.print(tmYearToCalendar(tm.Year));
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("registerByte3 = ");
    Serial.print(registerByte3, BIN);
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("registerByte2 = ");
    Serial.print(registerByte2, BIN);
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("registerByte1 = ");
    Serial.print(registerByte1, BIN);
    Serial.println();
  } else {
    if (RTC.chipPresent()) {
      Serial.println("The DS1307 is stopped.  Please run the SetTime");
      Serial.println("example to initialize the time and begin running.");
      Serial.println();
    } else {
      Serial.println("DS1307 read error!  Please check the circuitry.");
      Serial.println();
    }
    delay(9000);
  }
  delay(1000);
}

void print2digits(int number) {
  if (number >= 0 && number < 10) {
    Serial.write('0');
  }
  Serial.print(number);
}
```

Comment: Do you use a breadboard? Perhaps it is a bad connection. Did you solder it? perhaps there is a solder splat between two pins. Check the wiring, and try to  replace the bad 74hc595. Do you have a logic analyzer? If not, you can try to add delays and measure the signals with a voltagemeter.

Comment: I'm using a breadboard. I did try switching them around, and the problem is still there. I actually did buy three new registers, and I switched them around, the problem is still there. Sadly I'm not knowledgeable enough for the last 2 steps you mentioned. One thing to add is, on that first chip, the pins which are supposed to light up are brighter than the ones that arent supposed to.

Comment: Check the gnd of that 74hc595. Try to add another gnd wire or move that 74hc595 to a different location on the breadboard. Could you make a photo of it? This site is for questions and answers, you mention that the pins that are supposed to light up are brighter, please add that to your question, it is important information.